# Show that $\ln\ 2 \approx \frac{\pi^2}{16}\Bigl(1+\frac{\pi^2}{96}\Bigr)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Show the Maclaurin Series for $\ln(\cos\ x)=-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{12}x^4 + \ ...$ (1st part of the question already worked out )

Show that $\ln 2 \approx \frac{\pi^2}{16}\Bigl(1+\frac{\pi^2}{96}\Bigr)$

Given $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: well $\ln 2\approx x$, to any $x\in\Bbb C$

Comment: Hint: $2=\frac1{1/2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

Since $\cos(\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$, you can write $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)=\ln(2^{-1/2})=-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$$

---

*Edit for completion:*

*For small values of $\cos(x)$ we have* $$\ln(\cos x)\approx-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{12}x^4\tag{1}$$ *When $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ we get* $$-\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)=\ln(\cos \frac{\pi}{4})\approx-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^2-\frac{1}{12}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^4\\\ln(2)\approx\frac{\pi^2}{16}\left(1-\frac{\pi^2}{96}\right)$$